# When to add joins to a query

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

**Background**

We have a bunch of Java code which generates an SQL query. When generating the conditions for the WHERE part, we are having some difficulties inducing the necessary joins.
The purpose of the query is always to return the zoo's id (see Database Structure).

**Database Structure**

[image: Image of the database structure]

**Context**

In the UI the user defines separately the filtering logic and the WHERE clause pieces. An example

- Filtering logic: "1 OR (2 AND 3) OR (4 AND 5)"
- WHERE clause pieces:

  - 1: animal.name = "jack"
  - 2: zoo.city = "Los Angeles"
  - 3: animal.species = "bear"
  - 4: animal.species = "fish"
  - 5: animal.name = "henrietta"

**Problem**

The problem is that depending on the filtering logic and the WHERE clause pieces, extra joins might be necessary. At the very least new join is required when you have a query with like "(species = A AND name = B) AND (species = C AND name = D)" (both species and name columns are compared to different values while being in AND relation). Note that this query only makes sense because it is suppose to return the zoo's id where all of these conditions are true.

So my problem is that I do not know how many joins are absolutely necessary. I don't know the logic with which I will arrive at the answer. Because an extra join is not necessary if you have a query like "(species = A OR species = B)".

**Expected Behavior**

The following query should return the IDs of all zoos where there are two animals with names jack and tanya.

```
SELECT zoo.id FROM zoo
INNER JOIN animal a1 ON zoo.id = a1.zoo_id
INNER JOIN animal a2 ON zoo.id = a2.zoo_id
WHERE
a1.name = "jack"
AND a2.name = "tanya";
```

This query illustrates the need for two joins. The next one illustrates the case where only one join is sufficient.

```
SELECT zoo.id FROM zoo
INNER JOIN animal ON zoo.id = animal.zoo_id
WHERE
animal.name = "jack"
OR animal.name = "tanya";
```

**Naive Solution**

The simplest possible solution is to add one join for each animal table reference but there are serious performance consequences; increase of thousands of percents when compared to minimal joins.

Comment: Maybe I´m missing something, but why would you need extra joins here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt there's a good way around this.  You're going to have to write in quite a bit of intelligence here if it's completely dynamic.  However, you can probably 'cheat' by providing certain types of framework queries (ie, `has all animals`, etc), which would allow you to take some shortcuts.  There's a number of queries around here for "has all relationships".  Although I think you could get an `AND` and `OR` query down to (about) 3 joins, but I'm too tired now...

Answer (score 1):

This baseline for any query of what you have would be as follows...

```
SELECT
      a.species,
      a.name,
      z.city
   from
      animals a
         join zoo z
            ON a.zoo_id = z.id
```

Then, just add your query criteria into the WHERE clause, such as

```
   where
          ( a.name = 'jack' )
      OR  ( a.species = 'bear' AND z.city = 'Los Angeles' )
      OR  ( a.species = 'fish' AND a.name = 'henrietta' )
```

It goes through all the animals entries ONCE and pulls out those that qualify.  I would also have an index on animals by (species, name), and the zoo table indexed on (id, city)

Comment: This wouldn't work. I think you misunderstood the purpose. I have tried to further clarify the question by adding the section Expected Behavior; please review. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra joins.

Just join on the Zoo ID and you can add to the end of your statement "WHERE...."

EDIT: Are you doing "JOIN ON" ? If so, take the filter out of the join and just put it at the end.

Comment: Um, most (if not all) RDBMSs will throw a syntax error if a `JOIN` clause isn't followed by an `ON` clause.  This is a **good** thing - it puts the joining criteria with the thing being joined which makes it much more readable.  Putting things in the `WHERE` clause can have some rather unusual effects, depending on the specific type of join, and should generally be avoided.

Comment: You're saying this syntax is incorrect and will throw errors?  SELECT zoo.id FROM zoo
INNER JOIN animal ON zoo.id = animal.zoo_id
WHERE
animal.name = "jack"
OR animal.name = "tanya";

Comment: You're right, that should work fine.  Your answer sounds like you're completely remove the `ON` clause, which _would_ cause a syntax error.  Always put relevant conditions in the respective `ON` clause - it makes it more obvious what restrictions you're putting on the data.  For the most part, the `WHERE` clause should only be used for the `FROM` table-reference.  Note that most RDBMSs will auto-promote conditions to `JOIN` clauses anyways, when safe.  Note that moving conditions to the `WHERE` clause will change the meaning of `OUTER JOIN`s.  Oh, and your answer isn't helpful

Comment: I think my original question was not clear enough and that's the reason for this faulty answer. The joins are definitely needed since the query might want to have zoo IDs where there's animals of both species 'fish' and 'dog'. I have tried to clarify my question by adding the Expected Behavior section.